# "-role" option in Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-grid

What is the difference between "-role node" and "-role webdriver" in selenium grid ?

i.e.

is there any difference between

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar -role node -hub http://a.b.c.d:4444/grid/register

and

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.16.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://a.b.c.d:4444/grid/register

?

Comment: I did not find any difference, but there should be some. Did you check online docs? What do they say?\

Comment: I found the answer: 
Before, you needed 2 different nodes to have legacy ( rc ) and webdriver support.

Now, A single node can handle both, so "rc" and "wd" have been replaced by "node".

Answer (score 14):

Ok..I got the answer  :)

The following lines throws light on my question :

For backwards compatibility "wd"(webdriver) and "rc"(remotecontrol) roles are still a valid subset of the "node" role. But those roles limit the types of remote connections to their corresponding API, while "node" allows both RC and WebDriver remote connections.

Comment: upvoting for doing the homework :) "Google before post" should be the new "Think before you ask" ;) But no worries, I too do often the same. Asking the question out loud is the best way to start thinking of it ;)

Comment: Your answer helped me as I was wondering about the same question, so even if you answered yourself it still helped someone !